# Curve sketching: Desmos shows an oblique, absolute value asymptote

Tags: curves

I sketched the function $f(x) = x^{6/7}-9x^{2/7}$ and got something like this.

[image]

Where POI means point of inflection.

However, when I graph it in Desmos, I get what looks like an oblique asymptote, that corresponds to an absolute value function.

[image]

The more I zoom out though, the more the slope seems to decrease.

[image]

This shows (or at least lends credence) to the fact that there are two POIs, right? In addition, is it true that there is no asymptote?

This is my solution.

[image]

Comment: How did you find the locations of the minima and the inflexions?

Comment: I took the first derivative, and wrote down whether f'(x) was positive or negative in a given interval on a number line. That determined the local extrema. I did the same with f''(x) to find the concavity. This is my solution. http://imgur.com/ljJdtiS

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution. Your Desmos graph is wrong. Here is the correct Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fglop1ux1x  Or perhaps the scale on your Desmos graph is just inappropriate?

Comment: @MaxLi: Yes, your solution is OK.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Hi, I tried all kinds of scales and there always seemed to be an oblique asympotote, despite there being two POIs. Is that just a peculiarity of the graph, a kind of "don't trust your eyes, trust the math" kind of thing?

Comment: No, if you keep increasing the scale the slope of the apparent oblique asymptote keeps decreasing. Take $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{y}{x}$ and you will see that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there is no contradiction concerning your POI, with abscissas at $\pm (15)^{7/4} \approx \pm 114.3$ : it is impossible to spot them even on an large curve plainly because the transition from positive to negative concavity is **very faint**.

See graphics below obtained with Geogebra. The first one for the variations of function $f$, the second one for function $f''$, the latter graphics evidencing an extremely small variation (order $10^{-5}$), before and after the abscissa the transition at the POI.

Remark: $f''(x)=-\dfrac{6}{49}\dfrac{x^{4/7}-15}{x^{12/7}}.$

[image]

$$\text{Above: Curve of f}.$$

[image]

$$\text{Above: Curve of} \ f'' \ \text{ in the vicinity of a POI}.$$

Comment: What is the reason for the transition between concavities being so faint?

Comment: If you study the variations of $f''$ : its curve remains extremely close to the $x$ axis in a large region around (+115 ; 0). I  am going to give a plot of it, its amazing.

Comment: https://i.snag.gy/aZeCy3.jpg Why is there a third x-intercept for $f''$?

Comment: 1) I have added the curve of $f''$ in my answer.     2) Why do you believe there is a supplementary intercept at this point ? It is impossible: equation $x^{4/7}-15=0$ has a unique real positive root.

Comment: It must be a bug in desmos. Thank you!